# AngularJS routeProvider not adding hash at the end of URL

Tags: angularjs, routes, coffeescript, location-provider

I have the following routeProvider configured:

```
 angular.module('myModule').config ['$routeProvider', (provider) ->

   provider
  .when '',
     templateUrl: '/templates/dashboard.html'

  .when '/some_path/:some_param',
       templateUrl: '/templates/dashboard.html'
```

And the following in a wrapping statically served template:

I also have a templates/dashboard.html appropriately defined.

When I navigate to the url, the initial page loads, however a `#` is not postpended on the URL, which then results in errors when I try to rewrite the URL in a controller with `$location.path('fooPath')`.

Specifically `$location.path('fooPath')`, changes the URL to `current_dashboard_path/#/` and reloads, while what I was expecting is for the URL to be set to:

`current_dashboard_path/#/`, an then `location('fooPath')`, to change that to  `current_dashboard_path/#/fooPath`

Some additional context: I want to use this so that I can then use the `$location` service to change the url without reloading the page thus

Question is, how can I force Angular to postpend a `#` when an ng-view is populated.

Comment: have you looked into $location.hash('value'); ?

Comment: $location.hash('value'); changes the path to current_dashboard_path##value, rather then current_dashboard_path/#/value which still does not pass the right path params.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing the following line in my routeProvider:

```
 .when '/',
      templateUrl: '/templates/dashboard.html'
```

Additionally, the blank route

```
 .when '',
     templateUrl: '/templates/dashboard.html'
```

Needed to be removed

Then the way to rewrite the URL without reloading the page is the following in the controller:

```
 lastRoute = route.current

 scope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', (event)->
    route.current = lastRoute
 )
```